# Move forward and backwards between Items in QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I have a `QTreeView` with a `QStandardItemModel` and `QStandardItems`. I want to add buttons that lead from one element to the next or to the previous element. Getting the index from the current element works, but how to get the index from the next one or the one before it? Below is an example of the code. The missing code parts are indicated.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeView, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.Qt import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem


class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('World Country Diagram')
        self.resize(500, 700)

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)

        treeModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.rootNode = treeModel.invisibleRootItem()

        # America
        america = QStandardItem('America')

        california = QStandardItem('California')
        america.appendRow(california)

        oakland = QStandardItem('Oakland')
        sanfrancisco = QStandardItem('San Francisco')
        sanjose = QStandardItem('San Jose')

        california.appendRow(oakland)
        california.appendRow(sanfrancisco)
        california.appendRow(sanjose)

        texas = QStandardItem('Texas')
        america.appendRow(texas)

        austin = QStandardItem('Austin')
        houston = QStandardItem('Houston')
        dallas = QStandardItem('dallas')

        texas.appendRow(austin)
        texas.appendRow(houston)
        texas.appendRow(dallas)

        # Canada
        canada = QStandardItem('Canada')
        alberta = QStandardItem('Alberta')
        bc = QStandardItem('British Columbia')
        ontario = QStandardItem('Ontario')
        canada.appendRows([alberta, bc, ontario])


        self.rootNode.appendRow(america)
        self.rootNode.appendRow(canada)

        self.treeView.setModel(treeModel)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.treeView.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.display)
        self.button_next = QPushButton("Next", self)
        self.button_next.clicked.connect(self.next)
        self.button_before = QPushButton("Before", self)
        self.button_before.clicked.connect(self.next)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button_next)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_before)
        layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        window = QWidget()
        window.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(window)

    def display(self, ItemSelection):
        selection_model = self.treeView.selectionModel()
        index = selection_model.currentIndex()
        print(self.treeView.model().itemData(index))

    def next(self):
        selection_model = self.treeView.selectionModel()
        modelIndex = selection_model.currentIndex()
        # code missing
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(modelIndex)
        
    def before(self):
        selection_model = self.treeView.selectionModel()
        modelIndex = selection_model.currentIndex()
        #code missing
        self.treeView.setCurrentIndex(modelIndex)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

demo = AppDemo()
demo.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Get the selected item, then do something like `next = (item.parent() or item.model().invisibleRootItem()).child(item.row() + 1)`. (This will obviously return `None` if there's no next item).

Comment: With the approach I can jump back and forth within a grouping, but at the end of a grouping not to next one. For example, when I'm at San Jose in California, I can't jump to the next bracket of Texas.

Comment: I guessed that was probably what you wanted, since you didn't actually say. Getting the next item in the view is simply `tree.indexBelow(current)`.